# How to get baseband version of the device in android?

Tags: android, build, version, hardware

i am collecting hardware details of the device. i have got many hardware info's from `os.Build` only thing i am not getting is baseband version. Please help me to find it.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6):

In the past you could use the `Build.RADIO` static field in order to get the baseband (a.k.a Radio) version **which is however depraceted since SDK Lvl 14**.

Since SDK Lvl 14 you should use `Build.getRadioVersion()` in order to retrieve the baseband version.

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html